# Sequence of function depending on $n$ and $\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions in $\Bbb R$ that converges to $f(x)$. Then **can we write the following ?:**

"For every $\epsilon >0$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that $\displaystyle |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}n$ for all $n\ge N$ and for all $x\in \Bbb R$."

Is it correct? If not then can I expect a brief explanation? may be by an example.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence *Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions in $\mathbb R$ that converges to $f(x)$* is very confusing.

A sequence of functions can not converge to a number. Hence either you speak of [pointwise convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_convergence) meaning that for each $x \in \mathbb R$ $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges to $f(x)$. Or you're speaking of [uniform converge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence).

**You need to chose your battle!**

Answer (score 0):

If $f_n(x)=f(x)+\frac 1 n$ then $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ but the property you have stated fails whenever $\epsilon <1$.